# How do I display API data as a list in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of items

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "work_description": [
        "Did this and that",
        "Doing this and that",
        "Does that and that",
        "Do this and that"
    ],
    "company_name": "Google",
    "time_range": "April 2021 - Current",
    "position": "Sales"
}
```

I want to describe `work_description` as a list in Angular, but what I get is a paragraph of the details.
This is what I have:

```
• Did this and that, Doing this and that, Does that and that, Do this and that
```

This is what I want:

```
• Did this and that
• Doing this and that
• Does that and that
• Do this and that
```

Kindly assist

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf OR https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngfor/

Comment: I have used ```*ngFor``` and it still displays the data as a paragraph instead of a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<li *ngFor="let item of obj.work_description">{{item}}</li>
```